# changing columns names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change the names of the columns in a pandas dataframe. I use python 3.7. I have 30 columns numbered 0-29 and I want to change their names to 1-30. I know it's a silly question, but I'm trying to do it in minimum lines as possible, but I couldn't find anything efficient online. can anyone please help me?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to recreate the index with `RangeIndex`

```
df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df.columns)+1)
```

FYI, you can read the documentation about [**Int64Index and RangeIndex**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#indexing-rangeindex): *RangeIndex is an optimized version of Int64Index*

Answer (score 2):

If you have dataframe like this:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  a  d  e  f
1  b  g  h  i
2  c  j  k  l
```

Then you can do:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int) + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   1  2  3  4
0  a  d  e  f
1  b  g  h  i
2  c  j  k  l
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this. I believe you will find it short and simple enough.

```
 df.columns = [list(range(1,31))]
```

Comment: hi @franzmaliszt, This generates a MultiIndex and it can lead to subtle bugs e.g., after this, `df[5]` is still a dataframe and not a series! You might want to remove enclosing brackets to fix that issue (also you can remove `list`, too; but that's up to you).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, You can use list comprehension to rename your dataframe columns

```
 df = df[[i for i in range(1,30)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below ...

### Sample Data:

Just creating random sample data with 30 columns as follows, where we see the default `RangeIndex` starting Index startwith `0` by having `step=1`, which we can change to get the desired.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 30)))
print(df)
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
0   37  87  10  94  76  42  94  80   2  54  98  18  27  32  94  41  97  61  22  87  67  43  12  49  67  92  69  52  78  49
1   80  77  64  81  91  36  46  83  54  25  55   5   4  57  68  59  36  94  79  14  27   7  36  37  15   3   9  32  50  95
2   58  91  87  59  60  65  90  97  55  48  11  62  76  28  89  99  78  60  92  25  93  35  41  69  88  19  85  18  56  52
3   50   5  80  32  42  96  89  62  77  89  72   8   1   3  52  92  71  95  42  18   9  76   5  53  56  18  17   5   3  40
4   37  92  30  45  14  15  96  29   0  45  59  59  82  51  78  30  25  95  50  22  34  12  24  59  63   5  75  15  85  95
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
95  49  58   9  18  44  48  15  74  76  70  81  88  36  32  35  96  93  95   2  69  20  40  22  19  55  92  33  45  20  82
96  75  15  65  77   4   2  45  16  42  25  12  47  35  64   3  89  47  68  59  52  82  37  67  32  64  62   7  81  79  42
97   7  95  21  52  42  84   0  85   0   2  16  97  45  56  30  15  33  49  82  60  51  29   3  37  51   8  65  73  55  56
98  69  66  25  61  85  50  76  27  51  44  46  53  56  67  20  15   5  77  54  18  18  48  34   2  89  84  55  26  19   4
99  41  63  23  46  33  78  86  32   4   9  13  40  13  17  22  78  60  96  56   3  30  78  65  66  15  43  98  79  10  23
```

[100 rows x 30 columns]

```
print(df.columns)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=30, step=1)  <-- default behaviour
```

### Solution :

We can change the default `RangeIndex` to `start=1` as follows in order to get the result you desired.

```
df.columns = df.columns+1
print(df.columns)
RangeIndex(start=1, stop=31, step=1)

print(df)
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
0   37  87  10  94  76  42  94  80   2  54  98  18  27  32  94  41  97  61  22  87  67  43  12  49  67  92  69  52  78  49
1   80  77  64  81  91  36  46  83  54  25  55   5   4  57  68  59  36  94  79  14  27   7  36  37  15   3   9  32  50  95
2   58  91  87  59  60  65  90  97  55  48  11  62  76  28  89  99  78  60  92  25  93  35  41  69  88  19  85  18  56  52
3   50   5  80  32  42  96  89  62  77  89  72   8   1   3  52  92  71  95  42  18   9  76   5  53  56  18  17   5   3  40
4   37  92  30  45  14  15  96  29   0  45  59  59  82  51  78  30  25  95  50  22  34  12  24  59  63   5  75  15  85  95
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
95  49  58   9  18  44  48  15  74  76  70  81  88  36  32  35  96  93  95   2  69  20  40  22  19  55  92  33  45  20  82
96  75  15  65  77   4   2  45  16  42  25  12  47  35  64   3  89  47  68  59  52  82  37  67  32  64  62   7  81  79  42
97   7  95  21  52  42  84   0  85   0   2  16  97  45  56  30  15  33  49  82  60  51  29   3  37  51   8  65  73  55  56
98  69  66  25  61  85  50  76  27  51  44  46  53  56  67  20  15   5  77  54  18  18  48  34   2  89  84  55  26  19   4
99  41  63  23  46  33  78  86  32   4   9  13  40  13  17  22  78  60  96  56   3  30  78  65  66  15  43  98  79  10  23

[100 rows x 30 columns]
```

for more, you can look at the `help(df.columns)`

```
 |  start : int (default: 0), or other RangeIndex instance
 |      If int and "stop" is not given, interpreted as "stop" instead.
 |  stop : int (default: 0)
 |  step : int (default: 1)
 |  name : object, optional
 |      Name to be stored in the index.
 |  copy : bool, default False
 |      Unused, accepted for homogeneity with other index types.
 |
 |  Attributes
 |  ----------
 |  start
 |  stop
 |  step
 |
 |  Methods
 |  -------
 |  from_range
```